# Casting correct type in a map function in TypeScript/React

Tags: typescript, typeerror, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I am having trouble casting the correct type when mapping over an object in TypeScript/React.

I'm getting the following error: Property 'urls' does not exist on type 'object'.  TS2339

The only way I'm able to fix this is by setting any, which I realise is bad bad bad.

I tried creating an Interface with the properties present in the object but this didn't work.

I'm new to TypeScript so any help would be great. Thank you!

```
{images.map((image: object, key: number) => (
  <Image
    imageDesktop={image.urls.regular}
    imageMobile={image.urls.small}
    description={image.alt_description}
    author={image.user.name}
    url={image.links.html}
  />
))}

# Tried useing this Interface to set type to replace object, but got this error:

Argument of type '(image: ImageType, key: number) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: object, index: number, array: object[]) => Element'.
  Types of parameters 'image' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ImageType': urls, alt_description, user, links  TS2345

interface ImageType {
  urls: {
    regular: string;
    small: string;
  };
  alt_description: string;
  user: {
    name: string;
  };
  links: {
    html: string;
  };
}
```

Comment: "I tried creating an Interface with the properties present in the object but this didn't work." please elaborate on this point. Why did it not work? What kind of errors were you seeing?

Comment: I see a property `url`, but no property `urls`.

Comment: Don't use `object` type in this case. Use `Record<string, unknown>`

Comment: @AlexandervanOostenrijk I added this to my question, thank you :)

Comment: @captain-yossarian this is the error I got when I tried your idea: argument of type '(image: Record<string, unknown>, key: number) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: object, index: number, array: object[]) => Element'.
  Types of parameters 'image' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, unknown>'.
      Index signature is missing in type '{}'.  TS2345

    102 |                 animate="show"
    103 |               >
  > 104 |                 {images.map((image: Record<string, unknown>, key: number) => (

Comment: @lucasjohnson sorry, I was not clear enough. In general, you should avoid `object` and to use instead `Record<string, unknown>` if you don't know the values. In this case I think you should stick with MMD's solution

Comment: I do now the values through, they are all strings. I've tried to cast them as mentioned in my question but received the error above.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Use records for objects, like image:

   Record<string, any>

It means a record in which keys are strings and values can be "any" thing. Basically it's the definition of js objects. Use it if you just want your function to accept object.

2. Define a class with all the properties of your images and use the class name as a type. This is a better solution because you validate every property.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can create interfaces that fit your usage like this.

```
interface UrlType {
    regular: string;
    small: string;
}

interface UserType {
    name: string;
}

interface LinkType {
    html: string;
}

interface ImageType {
    urls: UrlType;
    alt_description: string;
    user: UserType;
    links: LinkType;
}

{
    // @ts-ignore
    images.map((image: ImageType, key: number) => (
        <Image
            imageDesktop={image.urls.regular}
            imageMobile={image.urls.small}
            description={image.alt_description}
            author={image.user.name}
            url={image.links.html}
        />
    ));
}
```

or 2. you may ignore all errors (but not recommended)

```
{
    // @ts-ignore
    images.map((image: object, key: number) => (
        // @ts-ignore
        <Image
            // @ts-ignore
            imageDesktop={image.urls.regular}
            // @ts-ignore
            imageMobile={image.urls.small}
            // @ts-ignore
            description={image.alt_description}
            // @ts-ignore
            author={image.user.name}
            // @ts-ignore
            url={image.links.html}
        />
    ));
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and added it to my question with the error output :)

Comment: @lucasjohnson please see the edit. I just added a simple `ts-ignore` that should solve your problem...